# How to use angular material (https://material.angularjs.org) in Angular 2 Apps?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular

I remember having seen angular-material.css being used in one of the Angular 2 Demos at ng-conf. Can someone confirm if this works...

Also, is it possible to use the following in Angular 2 Apps:

- angular-material.js
- angular-animate.js
- angular-aria.js

I know that above js have a dependency on Angular 1.3+, but what if I add that dependency over and above my Angular 2 dependency. Will these work then?

Answer (score 3):

So currently you cannot use the current angular material with angular2.

According to [Marcy Sutton](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1865#issuecomment-78204033), they will be addressing incorporation of Angular Material once the team has realeased 1.x.

https://github.com/angular/material2 is the new repo that will be compatible with ng2. There are some forks of Material that may work with ng2 already such as  [ng2-material](https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material).

Answer (score 0):

No, Angular Material 1.x does not support Angular 2+. You can see some of the issues and discussion around this in [issue #6336](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6336). Basically, many of the existing, tested components would need to be re-written (many months of work).

[material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) only recently (Dec 2016) entered beta and may not be ready for all production applications. If you need Material Design for your Angular 2 app ASAP, then contributing to material2 is your best option.

As far as I know, there is no Material Design library that is production ready (out of beta) for Angular 2+.

I was using [Angular2-Polymer](https://github.com/vaadin/angular2-polymer) with Polymer paper elements to get Material Design in my Angular 2+ applications, but breaking changes in Angular 2.2 have broken that integration and may require a significant re-write of the lib.

[Material Components for the Web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) may someday be another option, but they are in alpha atm.